# Is the model's prediction probability the same as the confidence level?

Tags: math, machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, classification

This question seems weird, let me explain it by example.

1. We train a particular classification model to determine if an image contains a person or not.
2. After the model is trained, we use an new image for predicting.
3. The predicting result show that there is 94% probability that the image contains a person.

Thus, could I say, the confidence level is 94%,  for that the image may contains a person?

Comment: Probability =/= Confidence, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third item is not properly interpreted.  The model returns a normalized score of 0.94 for the category "person".  Although this score correlates relatively well with our cognitive notions of "probability" and "confidence", do not confuse it with either of those.  It's a convenient metric with some overall useful properties, but it is *not* an accurate prediction to two digits of accuracy.

Granted, there may well be models for which the model's prediction *is* an accurate figure.  For instance, the `RealOdds` models you'll find on `538` are built and tested to that standard.  However, that is a directed effort of more than a decade; your everyday deep learning model is not held to the same standard ... unless *you* work to tune it to that, making the accuracy of that number a part of your training (incorporate it into the error function).

You can run a simple (although voluminous) experiment: collect all of the predictions and bin them; say, a range of 0.1 for each of 10 bins.  Now, if this "prediction" is, indeed, a probability, then your 0.6-0.7 bin should correctly identify a person 65% of the time.  Check that against ground truth: did that bin get 65% correct and 35% wrong?  Is the discrepancy within expected ranges: do this for each of the 10 categories and run your favorite applicable statistical measures on it.

I expect that this will convince you that the inference score is neither a prediction nor a confidence score.  However, I'm also hoping it will give you some ideas for future work.